# Can I use My Desktop Internal Hard Disk as Internal Laptop Hard Disk and Linux on it?

Tags: linux, windows-7, hard-drive, laptop, partitioning

I have a 3.5' Desktop Internal Hard Disk 320 GB. I want to install Linux Operating System. Can I install Linux on it as use it as my Internal Laptop Hard Disk????

Because I have Laptop as a Primary use for My work so can I use Computer's Internal Hard Disk and Use it as a Portable Linux Operating System in My Laptop??

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you can partition your Hard Drive and dual boot Windows and Linux, assuming you have Windows already installed.

Watch this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9gS5SoogltE

and this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rPUVIc-W13s

to learn more.

Comment: But I want to Dual boot my Desktop Internal Hard Disk not The Laptop Internal Hard Disk. Can I????